# Sphinx4 Beta API Problems With Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, beta, cmusphinx

I'm trying to set up a simple helloworld demo with Sphinx 4.0 (which is apparently a beta?) I downloaded the source and added it as source to Eclipse, but the problem is, it doesn't recognize a lot of the classes. I've been looking, and as far as I can tell, the classes it wants just aren't there! For example, the line:

```
import javax.speech.Central;
```

throws a compiler error, saying something about how the import couldn't be resolved. Is this a part of a bigger API I was supposed to download before trying to do Sphinx4? It didn't say anything about any other API but I'm open to the possibility.

If you want, I can post a list of all the imports that can't be resolved, I will, but that means looking through all the code which is kind of a pain. I have a hunch that I need to download the JSAPI, but I don't know which implementation would be good for Sphinx4.

Links to Sphinx4 downloads:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/1.0%20beta6/

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

EDIT: In addition, I've found a few lines that I think might mean I need to download JUnit? Again, I'm not totally sure how to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about this site is that the simple act of typing out a question and nervously analyzing it before finalizing any revisions (because, after all, someone WILL read this!) 95% of the time I answer my own question within 5 minutes of posting it.

Anyways, the solution was simple, I downloaded junit4-10.jar and jsapi.jar and added them to my Java build path. Then, I got more errors, and I said TO HECK with building from the source (which I was doing with sphinx4 here) and I just downloaded the already-built library and it works great. Got the HelloWorld I wanted!